# How to run Grails Database Migration after startup

Tags: grails, database-migration

For my integration tests I load a 'seed' database in bootstrap.groovy.
I also manually load up different databases from time to time during development to try out different scenarios.

Trouble is, the database migration plugin (many thanks Bert!) only seems to run during startup, before getting to the bootstrap code and I can't see anywhere I can trigger it to run again.

Which means if I load up a db that is 'out of date' then I have to shut down the app and restart it just to get the migration done. Then I have to remember to take a snapshot of the 'new' database so I don't have to do it again next time.

All of which really hits productivity, especially across multiple refactorings.

Are there better ways of doing this? Ideally I'd like service class method 'runMigrations()' or something. Then I could call it after my loading tools or from within my bootstrap code.

Any ideas?

Comment: Migrations aren't designed to be run post startup. They are designed to be run pre-startup for the reason of needing the schema to be correct prior to starting the application. You will need to use another tool to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible and it is a valid use case in my opinion, e.g. to run specific contexts after the application has been started:

```
import grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationUtils
import liquibase.Liquibase

class DatabaseMigrationService {

  def runMigrationsForContexts(String contexts) {
    def database = MigrationUtils.getDatabase()
    Liquibase liquibase = MigrationUtils.getLiquibase(database)
    liquibase.update(contexts)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Paul,

From my own personal experience, I've never seen the migration plugin run post start up. I don't believe it's coded to do that. I've been in a similar position as you where I'm switching databases, and I just had to keep stopping and starting the application.

Sorry!

Comment: Having trawled the net for several days, I'm coming to the same conclusion but I can't help feeling that, since Liquibase is a separate app which the dbmigration plugin is 'simply' calling then it should be possible to invoke it at will, so to speak. I guess we need Bert's input here...